# Able To Reference Functions But, Not Classes in a Namespace

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm able to reference functions from a namespace but, not classes. Here is the namespace file **SeqLib/FermiAssembler.h"**

```
#ifndef SEQLIB_FERMI_H
#define SEQLIB_FERMI_H

#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

namespace SeqLib 
{

    void print_my_name(){ std::cout << "It's Crt" }
    class FermiAssembler {
    public:
        FermiAssembler();

        ~FermiAssembler();

        void AddReads(const BamRecordVector& brv);
    };
}
```

I am able to call `print_my_name() via SeqLib::print_my_name()` but, not able to reference the FermiAssembler class via `SeqLib::FermiAssembler f`

Here is the C++ file within my `/src`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "SeqLib/FermiAssembler.h"
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void whats_my_name(){
     SeqLib::FermiAssembler f;
```

Here is the structure of the package

```
temp
  seqLib
  SeqLib
    src
      FermiAssembler.cpp
    SeqLib
      FermiAssembler.h
  headerFiles
    SeqLibCommon.h
  src
    hello_world.cpp
    Makevars which contains PKG_CXXFLAGS= -I../SeqLib
```

Here is **FermiAssembler.cpp** defined

```
 #include "SeqLib/FermiAssembler.h"
 #define MAG_MIN_NSR_COEF .1

 namespace SeqLib {
    FermiAssembler::~FermiAssembler() {
      ClearReads();
      ClearContigs();
    }
 }
```

The error message is: `Error in dyn.load(dllfile) :

  unable to load shared object 'temp/seqLib/src/SeqLib.so':

  temp/seqLib/src/SeqLib.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6SeqLib14FermiAssemblerD1Ev`

**update** I have moved the entire submodule into the src folder as such:

```
# temp
# |─── src 
#       |────SeqLib
#              |──────SeqLib 
#                        |────── FermiAssembler.h 
#              |──────src 
#                        |────── FermiAssembler.cpp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see an error referencing something like `_ZN6SeqLib14FermiAssemblerD1Ev`, the first step is to run it through a name demangler like `c++filt`, which should be included in any Linux distribution:

```
$ c++filt _ZN6SeqLib14FermiAssemblerD1Ev
# SeqLib::FermiAssembler::~FermiAssembler()
```

The problem is that in your header file you have **declared** a destructor for the class `FermiAssembler`, but did not provide a **definition** for it. Your options are

1. **Remove the declaration entirely.** If the destructor for this class is not doing anything special, such as freeing dynamically allocated memory, or logging information, etc., you should be fine with the default destructor generated by the compiler. However, if you provide a declaration such as you did above, you are telling the compiler *"the destructor for this class needs to do something extra so don't generate one for me"*.
2. **Provide an empty *definition***: `~FermiAssembler() {}` (note the braces, which distinguish this from a *declaration*). This is equivalent to using the compiler-generated destructor, as described above.
3. **Provide a non-empty *definition*.** In this simple example the `FermiAssembler` class does not need a non-default destructor, but for the purpose of demonstration we will explore this option below.

---

Here is the file layout I will be using; you will need to adjust your `#include` paths, etc. accordingly:

```
tree example/

# example/
# ├── DESCRIPTION
# ├── example.Rproj
# ├── NAMESPACE
# ├── R
# │   └── RcppExports.R
# └── src
#     ├── demo.cpp
#     ├── FermiAssembler.cpp
#     ├── FermiAssembler.h
#     └── RcppExports.cpp
```

---

The header `FermiAssembler.h` now becomes:

```cpp
#ifndef SEQLIB_FERMI_H
#define SEQLIB_FERMI_H

namespace SeqLib {

class BamRecordVector;

void print_my_name();

class FermiAssembler {
public:
    FermiAssembler();

    ~FermiAssembler();

    void AddReads(const BamRecordVector& brv);
};

} // SeqLib

#endif // SEQLIB_FERMI_H
```

Notice that I have also converted `print_my_name` to a function prototype, so it will also need to be defined in the corresponding source file. Additionally, you can move the previous `#include`s to the source file since they are no longer needed here:

```cpp
// FermiAssembler.cpp
#include "FermiAssembler.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Rcpp.h>

namespace SeqLib {

void print_my_name() {
    std::cout << "It's Crt";
}

FermiAssembler::FermiAssembler()
{
    Rcpp::Rcout << "FermiAssembler constructor\n";
}

FermiAssembler::~FermiAssembler()
{
    Rcpp::Rcout << "FermiAssembler destructor\n";
}

} // SeqLib
```

---

Finally, the file that make use of this class:

```cpp
// demo.cpp
#include "FermiAssembler.h"

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int whats_my_name() {
    SeqLib::FermiAssembler f;

    return 0;
}
```

---

After building and installing the package, it works as expected:

```r
library(example)
whats_my_name()
# FermiAssembler constructor
# FermiAssembler destructor
# [1] 0
```

---

**Update** Regarding your question of *"Can have source files in places other than the top level `src/` directory?"*, yes you can, but I would generally advise against this as it will require a nontrivial `Makevars` file. Now using this layout,

```
tree example

# example
# ├── DESCRIPTION
# ├── example.Rproj
# ├── man
# ├── NAMESPACE
# ├── R
# │   └── RcppExports.R
# ├── SeqLib
# │   ├── SeqLib
# │   │   └── FermiAssembler.h
# │   └── src
# │       └── FermiAssembler.cpp
# └── src
#     ├── demo.cpp
#     ├── Makevars
#     └── RcppExports.cpp
```

we have in the top level `src/` directory (**not** `SeqLib/src`) this `Makevars`:

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS= -I../SeqLib

SOURCES = $(wildcard ../SeqLib/*/*.cpp *.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(wildcard ../SeqLib/*/*.o *.o) $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
```

Note that in the above example we are simply compiling all object files into the same shared library. If you need to, for example, compile intermediate shared or static libraries and link them to the final `.so`, then expect your `Makevars` to get a lot messier.

---

Rebuilding and installing,

```
library(example)
whats_my_name()
# FermiAssembler constructor
# FermiAssembler destructor
# [1] 0
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer! I have actually defined the destructor in a separate file, please see the edited answer.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I edited the original question to include the **definition** of the destructor.

Comment: And? If you followed my advice, things should be working. If you are still having issues you need to add those details to your question.

Comment: I meant that the original package has a definition for the destructor. You said above that "The problem is that in your header file you have declared a destructor for the class FermiAssembler, but did not provide a definition for it," but, I already have a destructor defined. Wouldn't that solve the problem? I still have one however and it's the same one..

Comment: Currently you have `FermiAssembler.cpp` in `PACKAGE_ROOT/SeqLib/src`. Move it to `PACKAGE_ROOT/src`.

Comment: Is it possible to keep it within PACKAGE_ROOT/SeqLib/src because SeqLib is a submodule and would like it to be updated automatically.

Comment: For the record, I showed you `c++filt` yesterday but you chose to delete your own question only to repost it slightly altered.  That is a good way to demotivate folks you might otherwise spend time on your questions...

Comment: Sorry, @DirkEddelbuettel. I deleted it because you and another said I should reword the question and I tried to include the structure of the package as well as the code to the header file. I honestly tried to make it more answerable after reading how to make a reproducible example.

Comment: @nrussell I've included the FermiAssembler.cpp in the /src folder but, a new error is outputted: Error in dyn.load(dllfile) : unable to load shared object '/temp/seqLib/src/SeqLib.so': temp/seqLib/src/SeqLib.so: undefined symbol: fml_correct

Comment: Well, did you declare a function named `fml_correct` somewhere?

Comment: @nrussell thanks for the help! I followed your guideline about keeping all source code within the package's root src/ folder. I moved an entire submodule there that contains header files and source files in separate directories. I ran the c++filt and the destructor is still having trouble in finding the source code. Is there a way to specify the path to the src code?

Comment: Is your package on GitHub? I really can't say what you are doing wrong without seeing your file layout and Makevars.

Comment: The SeqLib submodule is actually in the src/ folder

Comment: *"and the destructor is still having trouble in finding the source code"* -- I find it hard to believe that you were able to successfully compile the package and reach a point where you would get such an error again. The structure of your real package is **significantly** more complicated than what you presented here, as it contains nested submodules with non-trivial compilation requirements: **(1)** both `SeqLib/` and `SeqLib/htslib` contain `configure` scripts that would need to be run; **(2)** many of these files use C++11 features, which your Makevars does not specify;

Comment: **(3)** there are various missing dependencies in the included files that result in compilation error (e.g. `../SeqLib/seq_test/seq_test.cpp:699:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BOOST_TEST'`); **(4)** your Makevars file needs to set include flags *and* add compilation rules (similar to what I have above) for **all** of the relevant subdirectories.

Comment: Given all of the above, this question is **far** too broad to be considered on topic; and in the future, you need to make sure that the example problem you present is actually representative of your real scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should of better represented the problem, which I will do in future scenarios. Thanks again.