# Running submodule configure script Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

I have the following structure of an Rcpp package:

```
# SeqLib
#   |-----src 
#          |-----SeqLib(a submodule) 
                    -configure script
```

I have a submodule that contains a configure script. How would I specify the execution of it via the Makevars file or any other way.

Update:

```
Detailed structure:
# SeqLib
#   |-----src 
#          |-----SeqLib(a submodule) 
#                   - configure script 
#                   - SeqLib 
#                       - FermiAssembler.h 
#                   - src 
#                       - FermiAssembler.cpp
```

The reason for this is from advice on this question [Able To Reference Functions But, Not Classes in a Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353191/able-to-reference-functions-but-not-classes-in-a-namespace)

Basically, I have a header file in a separate directory than the definition file. It looks like there is a problem with not being able to find the definition of the cpp file by using `c++filt.`

Comment: Try `(cd SeqLib; ./configure [options])` -- but if this contains Rcpp, is it meant to be loaded by R?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thank you for the response and yes, the package is meant to be run through R.

Comment: Then unless you _really_ know what you are doing I would recommend sticking with the _existing_ package format and layout which is widely used, tested and working.

Comment: Which existing package format are you referring to? Would it still be possible to run the SeqLib submodule code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Dirk Eddelbuettel, the following worked:

```
(cd SeqLib; ./configure)
```